# does not respond to selector image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

Thank you for reading, and here is my problem.
I am trying to save a picture (which I have taken using the UIImagePickerController methods) though I have an error. The error is "Does not respond to selector image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)

I have read elsewhere that it is something to do with changing an instance method to a class method (but I am a noob and have no idea what that means.) Here is my code :D.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {



// Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

// Save image 
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
}
```

I have been told it's something to do with the "Self" in the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum method.

Answer (score 4):

use this code to save your selected image:

```
 -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
 UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image,self,  
                                   @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),
                                   nil);
}
```

and add this function too.

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo: (void *)contextInfo
{
if (error != nil) 
 {
    NSLog(@"Image Can not be saved");
 } 
 else 
 {
    NSLog(@"Successfully saved Image");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class (self) doesn't respond to selector **image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:**.
You should make an implementation of this selector.
Something like this

```
- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save image");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Saved image");
    }
}
```